# ASP.NET MVC5 OWIN: Why User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false after signing in via Facebook?

Tags: facebook, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, owin

I am following the example of the VS2013 SPA Template - however am not using Bearer Tokens (this maybe the problem but would like to get this working just with cookies if possible).

Here is a cut down version of the relevant action method in my API Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
    {

        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
        }

        ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

        // ...do stuff with externalLogin data
   }
```

Here is the basic flow of requests:

1. Users clicks Facebook button, sends GET to /api/externallogin?provider=Facebook
2. User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns false -> results in 401 being returned and middleware converts that into a 302 with the 'Location' header set to the facebook login page
3. Browser goes to the facebook login page 
   (`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id={myClientId}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54819%2Fsignin-facebook&scope=user_birthday&state={someStateCode}`)
4. User signs in via Facebook -> results in browser making a call to the 'redirect_uri' but now with 'code' and 'state' parameters in the query string i.e. `http://localhost:54819/signin-facebook?code={someCode}&state={someStateCode}`
5. Response from the call to the 'redirect_uri' is a 302 with Location header set back to my application and also contains two 'Set-Cookie' headers:

   - Location: `http://localhost:54819/api/en-gb/account/externallogin?provider=Facebook`
   - Set-Cookie: .AspNet.Correlation.Facebook=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
   - Set-Cookie: .AspNet.ExternalCookie=Rv01CHd2onYtN_MHw2Bt71JSaOP71uRk7AP6kSilnAg7djXMh5fbZxlRCPuZhy8inhEF7ChNB261WVU3LGDuIaQmMXgz7tqXeNI-ji8qQFi2d64a720PbRVpWnkuHm2m8L87fkJAGQMJOku5gMrc0EZJfKNgjXiLv-c6Vo7PEzNch-CqcCPFHP0KBo7tGhDTbgJt-RvTzkkB1NL2JBc23eiaeda70oAW4P0NfIyj_i9mLUexHXz8Qooy9CBoLrN7Z198H_cawBfiMMF0tK1YFee2eH_TQxdmdKkUFVRz58EeIKyKUEEDswbQA9evPEHpD8BIlJPXi6R2scC44_INufXuKjHOt7LW3-sPRkUGbEWCWOn4d1B4FkHR_xOHtRpGpIdZU14xJLLiyFYKR0XxJiRlRIph8KKYnZHy61wMOl2yznOFqq3rzHOGhZ1xXEKmUlByiawPbNpdS9pNZVSHlGMbiz0FsOTf4_EVAKEXRQyxEbYjBBXD_5Ne6f7SpBqE; path=/; HttpOnly
6. Browser then sends GET request to the URL in the Location header from step 5 (back to my application), with the following cookie (as per the above 'Set-Cookie' directive):

   - Cookie:  .AspNet.ExternalCookie=Rv01CHd2onYtN_MHw2Bt71JSaOP71uRk7AP6kSilnAg7djXMh5fbZxlRCPuZhy8inhEF7ChNB261WVU3LGDuIaQmMXgz7tqXeNI-ji8qQFi2d64a720PbRVpWnkuHm2m8L87fkJAGQMJOku5gMrc0EZJfKNgjXiLv-c6Vo7PEzNch-CqcCPFHP0KBo7tGhDTbgJt-RvTzkkB1NL2JBc23eiaeda70oAW4P0NfIyj_i9mLUexHXz8Qooy9CBoLrN7Z198H_cawBfiMMF0tK1YFee2eH_TQxdmdKkUFVRz58EeIKyKUEEDswbQA9evPEHpD8BIlJPXi6R2scC44_INufXuKjHOt7LW3-sPRkUGbEWCWOn4d1B4FkHR_xOHtRpGpIdZU14xJLLiyFYKR0XxJiRlRIph8KKYnZHy61wMOl2yznOFqq3rzHOGhZ1xXEKmUlByiawPbNpdS9pNZVSHlGMbiz0FsOTf4_EVAKEXRQyxEbYjBBXD_5Ne6f7SpBqE
7. **THE PROBLEM**: User.Identity.IsAuthenticated check returns False at this stage (in fact the User field is basically empty)

I would have thought, given that the AspNet.ExternalCookie is definitely being sent in the request at step 6 then the user is thereby Authenticated.

So, does anyone know what the middleware would be looking for at this stage in order for it to decode/decrypt/de-serialize the cookie and saturate the User???

Here is the Startup.Auth I have:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            //AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            AuthenticationType = Constants.AuthenticationTypes.MchAdminApplicationCookie,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0)
        });

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            //AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            AuthenticationType = Constants.AuthenticationTypes.MchApiApplicationCookie,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0)
        });

        var facebook = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "mycode",
            AppSecret = "mysecret",

            AuthenticationType = "Facebook",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = async ctx =>
                {
                    if (ctx.User["birthday"] != null)
                    {
                        ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, ctx.User["birthday"].ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        facebook.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebook);
    }
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this JTech? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. You should add two attributes to ExternalLogin action:

```
[OverrideAuthentication]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
```